# How to save user log-in state in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, credentials

I'm trying to build an app with a login module. I want to save the user login state so that the end-user will not have to retype his/her credentials except if they have explicitly logged out.

I understand that `SharedPreferences` can be of some use but I would appreciate it if some one can provide me some of their expert insight in this matter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use the below link.There is 3 way to store you login details . one is using shared preference and 2nd one way is store in a file and the third one is using sqlite.   This will give you the ideas for storing login details.

[save user data](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/17/data-storage-mechanisms-in-android/)

Comment: Asish, thank you for your response. It did help me figure out in which direction to proceed. Others, may also find this link useful: http://www.mobilecoders.net/?q=node/7

Comment: Link no longer works.

Answer (score 8):

You can use any of the three methods that Asish AP references. But for a small amount of data (one user's username, password, login state) SharedPreferences is probably the lightest / easiest.

But whichever way you go, you should make sure that you encrypt whatever you store using one of the Java encryption methods at [Encrypt Password in Configuration Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files-java). Having plaintext credentials sitting around (eg on the SD card) is just way too vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I guess, I will just proceed with saving the userId and let the user enter the password when required.