# Hide password in Java source code

Tags: java, security, proguard

I need to hide the password in the source, what are the possible methods to obfuscate the password in order to reduce the risk of decompilation?

e.g.

```
final String password = "secret";
```

Comment: Why is the password hard coded in the source? Is there no way of externalising it?

Comment: @Lloyd This is the chicken and egg problem, if you externalizing it, maybe store in an encrypted config file, you still need a key to decrypt it?

Comment: An important concern is what kind of application is it, specifically how will it be deployed? Desktop? Mobile? Web?

Comment: You can make the password file only readable by the user account which runs the application (and you can encrypt it as well if you want) i.e. use file system security.

Comment: Another important one is what are you trying to protect and from whom? The user, someone else, or anyone but you (i.e. admin)?

Comment: @Howard I was thinking more along the lines of PKCS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, I wouldn't name my variable `password`.**

Second, I wouldn't keep it in raw format, but encode it.

Third, I'd use a `char[]` instead of `String` (because strings reside in the string pool).

Of course the best option would be to not keep it in the code at all.

Comment: but wouldn't ProGuard change the variable names anyway?

Answer (score 17):

Don't bother.

Your average user won't be able or willing to decompile class files anyway, and a motivated and skilled attacker won't be held back by obfuscation when the target is a single piece of data. All it takes is one such motivated and skilled attacker and the whole world knows the password.

If your security depends on obfuscating a password, you have already lost.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the password using an external method, a method that can be used decrypt within your code and store the password (encrypted) on your code

Answer (score 0):

Use database or file to save your pasword. Here is pretty good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files-java) with example.
But still you need to store somewhere one master password to encrypt your passwords. Tt's hard to protect it from being found and misused to decrypt your passwords :(.