# Obfuscating password parameters inside a JSON using Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, json

I would like to obscure certain password type words within a json string, such that the following:

```
"password":"foobar1"
```

would be replaced with

```
"password":"XXXXX"
```

or

```
"pwd":"foobar1"
```

would be replaced with

```
"pwd":"XXXXX"
```

I was able to do it using the following Pattern and replaceAll method

```
REGEX_JSON_PASSWORD = 
    Pattern.compile("\"(?i)(password|pwd)\":\"[\\w\\p{Punct}&&[^&]]*?\"");
replacementString = 
    REGEX_JSON_PASSWORD.matcher(returnMe).replaceAll("\"$1\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"");
```

I don't like having to add the double quotes in the replacement string, but if I don't add them, all I get is

```
pwd:foobar1
```

(no quotes)

Is there a more efficient way of implementing the replaceAll than what is show above?

Comment: Don't bother creating your own "security encryption", just use one of the built in cryptography APIs such as `javax.crypto.Cipher`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files-java).

Comment: Not only is that a bad idea, but it is also a bad idea to use regexes to modify JSON. There are JSON libraries for this (Jackson in particular is fantastic at "JSON edition").

Comment: ok, I did not get your question, to be clear: you want to replace whatever full text password is showing by a string containing only XXXX.

Comment: please, use the verb "obfuscate" instead of "encrypt", so that there can't be any confusion in your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a good way is to use a json parser to make change into your JSON.

With your method:

change your pattern and your replacement to:

```
pattern: (?<=\"(?i)p(?>assword|wd)\":\")[^\"]++ 
replacement: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

With this you avoid quotes question and backreference in the replacement, cause you have matched only what you need: foobar1

Answer (score 2):

afaict, string replacement are better done using regular expressions, as ugly as they may look like.

I think with the following you nailed it:

```
REGEX_JSON_PASSWORD = Pattern.compile("\"(?i)(password|pwd)\":\"[\\w\\p{Punct}&&[^&]]*?\"");
replacementString =  REGEX_JSON_PASSWORD.matcher(returnMe).replaceAll("\"$1\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"");
```

If you keep the `REGEX_JSON_PASSWORD` instanciated once, and apply the `replacementString` on each string.

But if you feed your data to a JSON parser, like gson, you may want to replace the password string just before it gets serialized to JSON, and thus just make a plain stupid replace of the value of your string. But that will all depend on the context of your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this in PHP-land:

```
// Obfuscate / mask password in JSON string
$json = preg_replace('/"(pass|password)":"(.*?)"/i', '"$1":"****"', $json);
```