# how to encrypt using two string in JAVA

Tags: java, security, encryption

How can I encrypt and decrypt text by using two string
for more clarification

```
String order =  {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z};
String random = {q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m};
```

when i encrypt any word for example : abcdefg ;
when i encrypt it it will shown as qwerty ;

and when i decrypt he will do the reverse
if he write hello the decrypted text will be  pcssi

i try hard to use the index of the two strings but i couldn't find any result

Comment: Using an array of char might be simpler to encrypt and decrypt. If you can't use array, you should remove the `,` and `{}` from your String objects to make it simpler too.

Comment: Show us what you tried. The only two lines of code that you showed are not even valid Java code.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking.  Are you asking why your decrypt isn't working?

Comment: Is this homework or similar?

Comment: HOW are you encrypting, is the important thing here.

Comment: @Chris Despite calling it encryption, what he actually tries is substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is likely a homework, here are some hints on how to complete it:

- You need to fix the syntax: string literals go in double-quotes with no commas
- To "encode" a character, find its position in the `order` string using `indexOf`, then use that index in the call of `random.charAt`.
- To "decode" a character, do the same thing in reverse order: call `indexOf` on `random`, then pass the index to `order.charAt`.

Here is a skeletal code to encode a single character, and decode it back ([demo](http://ideone.com/b4opt7)):

```
char orig = 'x';
char conv = random.charAt(order.indexOf(orig));
char back = order.charAt(random.indexOf(conv));
```

This code is incomplete - it is going to fail if the character being looked up is *not* present in the `order` string, or when either the `order` or the `random` string do not cover the entire alphabet exactly once.

Note: this implementation of a primitive [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) has nothing to do with security: if anything, it makes your system *less* secure by pretending to encode things which essentially remain in plain text.

Comment: THANKS a lot but it isnt a homework 
iam going to develop a program for encryption and decryption using more than one algorithms 
so that thanks another time and i will done it 
thanks for help

Comment: @EngHashem You are welcome! Try this out and see if it works. If it does, consider accepting an answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Comment: @EngHashem As others have already pointed out, this mechanism can hardly be considered encryption. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132567/851811) for an example of a basic two-way password encryption.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're not forced to use strings**

Your best option here would to use an `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`. The objective here is to "bind" one letter to another, allowing you to find a `key` (for example the `a`), and retrieve the `value` (the encrypted one, in this case the `q`). When you need to decrypt, you can with a bit of coding find the `key` that belongs to your `value` from the same table. Assuming you use a 1 to 1 encryption like in your example, you will be able to do this relatively easily.

**else**

Use the `charAt(int pos)` method as described in some of the other responses here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Encription {
    
    private String text;
    private int key;
    
    public Encription(String text, int k){
        this.text = "";
        key = k;//(int)(Math.random()*5);
        String[] tokens = text.split(" ");
        for(int i = tokens.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            for(int j = 0; j < tokens[i].length(); j++)
                this.text += (char)(tokens[i].charAt(j) + key);
            this.text += " ";
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString()  {
        
        return text;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Encription e;// = new Encription("Humming birds hum on trees");
        java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        boolean ans = true;
        while(ans){
            int key = -1;
            while(key <= 0 || key > 5){
                System.out.print("Enter a key value between 1 and 5: ");
                key = scan.nextInt();
            }
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter text: ");
            String phrase = scan.nextLine();
            e = new Encription(phrase, key);
            
            System.out.println("The encrypted text is: "+e);
            System.out.println("Do you wish to enter another text? (y/n)");
            char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
            ans = (c=='y' || c== 'Y');
            
        }
        
    }
}
```