# Encrypting a password within a Spring configuration file

Tags: java, spring, encryption, jasypt

I have a Spring bean which uses a username/password as part of its constructor parameters :

```
<bean id="mysender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
         <property name="c">
             <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
                 <constructor-arg value="plaintext"/>
                 <constructor-arg value="plaintext"/>
             </bean>
         </property>
     </bean>
```

Can I use jasypt to encrypt these parameters from the configuration file only ? The bean "org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials" will be instantiated with plain text values but to the user they will appear encrypted.

I could use core java library code using this answer : [Encrypt Password in Configuration Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files-java) and manually create the bean mysender from within java, then depcript the fields before instantiating org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials

Or is there a tried method of I have not mentioned which will implement this ?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this? Is the password something that will change on a per-installation basis, or is it similar to an API key that's for your application as a whole?

Comment: @chrylis it is a requirement that plaintext credentials are not to be stored in configuration files. The password will change on a per installation basis

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to externalize them into a properties file or JNDI?

Comment: @chrylis im not sure I follow. Perhaps it does'nt make sense but this is the implementation and is one I have to follow

Comment: Can you use the JavaConfig syntax? It would be very easy to write a method that takes the encrypted value (and maybe a key) as input, decrypts the password, and constructs the client object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jasypt can handle this.  See

http://www.algowise.com/2013/04/encrypting-passwords-using-jasypt-in.html

Comment: When I web-searched for this exact question, the Jasypt docs for Spring integration at http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html were the result immediately preceding this SO question.  They are very direct and comprehensive.  Myself, I'm going to go the "externalize to a properties file" route as in the second section instructs.  The other Jasypt docs provide details on different PBE configuration besides use of an environment variable to store the crypto password.