# Encrypting a password to be stored in a file with PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256 in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt a password that I need to store in a flat file to be accessed by my java application. I used the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files#1133815) to model my solution, and it works. Since I know close to nothing about cryptography algorithms, once I read about how weak DES is I wanted to pick another algorithm, and I chose `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256`. When I was using `PBEWithMD5AndDES`,

```
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
....
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
```

was enough to decrypt the string, but with this algorithm I get this exception:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Missing parameter type: IV expected
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Core.engineInit(PBES2Core.java:252)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:806)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
```

and the only way I could get the decryption to work was if I pass the encryption cipher's algorithm parameters to the decryption one, like this:

```
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
AlgorithmParameters ap = pbeCipher.getParameters();
....
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ap);
```

Which does not work for me cause I need to be able to decrypt if the application was restarted in the meantime.
So, my question: is this simply how this algorithm is supposed to work, and in that case should I pick a different stronger one (or should I bother at all), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And what exception do you get when you use the old code with the new encryption parameter?

Comment: @GabrielVince I have updated the question with the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AES cipher needs an extra algorithm parameter - the IV. You can treat it as another SALT (can be random, stored together with the password). The IV for your alg spec should be 16 bytes long

```
public static String encrypt(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENC_ALG);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALG);

    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), SALT, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);    
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 0,ivSpec);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENC_ALG);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALG);

    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), SALT, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);    
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 0, ivSpec);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
    return new String(decrypted);
}
```

Comment: Note, the 3 argument `PBEParameterSpec` is new in Java 8.

Comment: PBEParameterSpec is since from Java 1.4.   However - this is really a sample using Java 8 and not all methods (or constructors) may be present in older versions. But the basic idea is still valid - the AES cipher expects the IV to be specified and I suggest to do that explicitly at the encryption time as well.

Answer (score 3):

An [**Initialization Vector (IV)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) is a fixed-size piece of random data needed to initiate the encryption & decryption process. When decrypting, this piece of data needs to be the same as was used when encrypting.

When using **PBEWithMD5AndDES** the **IV** is derived from the password, and thus don't need to be specified on the decrypt.

However, with **PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256** the **IV** is random with each encrypt (independently of the password), and thus need to be provided on the decrypt.

You can grap it from the encryption cipher with `pbeCipher.getIV();`

Usually the **IV** is pre-pended to the encrypted data. It don't need to be secret.