# It is possible to get the kony crypto algorithm in java

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, password-encryption, temenos-quantum

My use-case is to re-create the client side(browser) manipulation such as encryption in Java program.

I could see a website uses the kony framework generate a encrypted value.
Details of Kony Framework in Javascript : http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_api_dev_guide/content/kony.crypto_functions.htm

I would like to understand do we have any equivalent java code to implement the kony crypto algorithm in java?

Comment: You can find in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files

Comment: Thanks @PhuDuy . In that link i could an alternate encryption implementation, but i am in need of equivalent for kony crypto algorithm in java

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to achieve the same in Java. Kony Crypto APIs work only on the device side. IF you are looking forward to achieve end-to-end encryption, then you can try CryptoJS library.  You can encrypt at device and send it across network and perform the decryption using Java services/preprocessor.

Link for CryptoJS Lib: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/